Why does $\lim(\inf (a_n +b_n))=\lim( \inf(a_n) )+ \lim (\inf(b_n))$ fail?
I was working on the proof that for bounded sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$, $\liminf_{n\to\infty}(a_n)+\liminf_{n\to\infty} (b_n) \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} (a_n+b_n)$. I got to a point where I concluded that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\inf (\{a_k +b_k | k \geq n\}))=\lim_{n\to\infty} (\inf(\{a_k | k\geq n\})) + \lim_{n\to\infty} (\inf(\{b_k |k \geq n\}))$ then $\liminf_{n\to\infty} (a_n)+\liminf_{n\to\infty} (b_n) = \liminf_{n\to\infty} (a_n+b_n)$.
I know that this not correct and a strict inequality is possible (for example), but I'm not sure why exactly the algebraic limit theorem fails to apply here. I know the algebraic limit theorem fails for divergent sequences, but found that $\lim \inf$ and $\lim \sup$ always exist and are finite for bounded sets.
So my questions is: why does the algebraic limit theorem not apply here?

What do you mean with "algebraic limit theorem"?

What's $\inf(a_n)$ supposed to mean? $a_n$ is not a set. The algebraic limit theorem does not apply here because $\liminf_n a_n$ is not $\lim(\inf(a_n))$, whatever that's supposed to mean. It is the limit of a sequence, but not that of $a_n$.

By algebraic limit theorem I mean : "given $\lim(a_n)=a$ and $\lim(b_n)=b$, then $lim(a_n+b_n)=a+b$".   By $\inf(a_k)$, I mean $inf(a_k | k \geq k)$, so $\lim(\inf(a_n)$ should be $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\inf( {a_k | k \geq n})$    (I'll update the notation in the question).

The usual limit law is
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \Big[ \, \inf_{n > N} \left( {a}_{n} \right) + \inf_{n > N} \left( {b}_{n} \right) \Big] = \lim_{N \to \infty} \inf_{n > N} \left( {a}_{n} \right) + \lim_{N \to \infty} \inf_{n > N} \left( {b}_{n} \right).$$
The problem is that
$$\inf_{n > N} \left( {a}_{n} + {b}_{n} \right) \neq \inf_{n > N} \left( {a}_{n} \right) + \inf_{n > N} \left( {b}_{n} \right)$$
in general.

Good point, and in retrospect something I should have said in my answer as well. +1

Oh ok, I was thinking that since for sets A & B, $\inf(A+B)=\inf(A) +\inf(B)$,  $\inf_{n > N}( {a}n + {b}n) = \inf{n > N} ( {a}n ) + \inf{n > N}( {b}{n})$ would be true. But ${a_n}+{b_n}={a_i+b_j| i\in n, j\in n} $ and $ {a_k+b_k | k \in n}$ are actually different sets.

Thank you! This is exactly what my problem was.

The idea is that the sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ can conspire to have their combined $\operatorname{liminf}$ being lower.
Take an explicit example $a_n = n \mod 2$ and $b_n = 1-a_n$. They are both alternating sequences. The $\operatorname{liminf}$ of each of these sequences is $0$.
Note that $a_n+b_n = 1$ for any $n$ so the $\operatorname{liminf}$ of $a_n+b_n$ is $1$.


I know the algebraic limit theorem fails for divergent sequences, but found that liminf and limsup always exist and are finite for bounded sets.

The crucial thing to note here is that bounded does not imply convergence.
Let's consider the same example you linked. Sequences $a_{n} = (-1)^{n}$ and $b_{n}=-(-1)^{n}$. It's easy to see that
$\lim\inf a_{n} = \lim\inf b_{n} = -1$. Further, it's obvious both of these sequences are bounded, but neither is convergent!
However, if we define $c_{n} = a_{n}+b_{n}$,  it's obvious that $c_{n}$ is constant and equal to $0$. Therefore, $\lim\inf (a_{n}+b_{n})=\lim\inf c_{n} = 0$
Ps: Im using $\lim\inf a_{n}$ as shorthand for the notation used in the problem.

The problem here is that the applicability of the algebraic limit theorem here relies upon the convergence of $(\inf_{k\geq n} (a_k)){n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(\inf{k\geq n} (b_k)){n\in \mathbb{N}}$, not the convergence of $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$. And I believe $(\inf{k\geq n} (a_k)){n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(\inf{k\geq n} (b_k))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ do converge due to be non-decreasing and bounded.
